# Display Django Field properties, such as min_value and max_value, in the Template

Tags: python, django, forms, field

I have a Django Form with an IntegerField. I give the IntegerField a min_value and a max_value. I would like to DISPLAY that min_value and max_value for the user, so I'm trying to include it in the template next to the input field itself. Seems like this should not be so hard, but it isn't working. :-(

Below, the "print" statement in views.py works just fine. So I know that one can access the min_value from the field with just ".min_value". But the min_value in the template does not show up in the browser.

Thoughts anyone??

In forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    somenumber = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=12)
```

In views.py:

```
form = forms.MyForm()
print(form.fields['somenumber'].min_value)
...
context = {'form':form}
...
```

In template:

```
{{ form.somenumber.min_value }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access `form.field` you are not actually getting the field you defined on the form, you are getting a [`BoundField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/boundfield/). You can access the field you defined by access the `field` attribute of the bound field

```
{{ form.somenumber.field.min_value }}
```

Comment: Oh wow. THANK YOU. I wish I hadn't spent so much time on this before asking the universe :-) Thank you a million.

Comment: to be clear,  you need to add .field  after the name field.  I was confused at first